# Getting null value in " st " reffrence variable in my ShowServlet.java file?

Tags: java, servlets

Student.java

```
public class Student {

    String name;

    String id1,phone,clas;

    public Student(String  id,String n,String ph,String c) {
         id1=id;
         name=n;
         phone=ph;
         clas=c;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return  "Name: "+name+" Address: "+clas+" Phone: "+phone+" ID:" +id1;
    }
}
```

StudentDAO.java

```
import java.sql.*;

public class StudentDAO {   

    public Student searchinfo(String id1) {
        Student  st = null;
        try {
            String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Asim Iqbal\\Documents\\IT.accdb";
            Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String sql= "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID=?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1,id1);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()) {
                String i=rs.getString("ID");
                String nam=rs.getString("Name");                  
                String ph=rs.getString("Phone");
                String clas=rs.getString("Class");
                st = new Student(i,nam,ph,clas);    
            }
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return st;
    }            
}
```

ShowServlet.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        String id=request.getParameter("id1");
        StudentDAO stdDAO=new StudentDAO();
        Student st=stdDAO.searchinfo(id);
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Search Result</h1>");
        if(st!=null) {
            out.println("<h3>" +st.toString()+ "</h3>");
        }
        else {
            out.println("<h3>Sorry, No record found</h3>");
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Please suggest me where i am getting wrong...

Comment: you do not get any other errors and you are sure you have data in that table?

Comment: yup, i am getting data from DB, i have check it separetly..

Comment: the only way st would be null is if an exception is thrown in the searchInfo method. please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: Are you sure the string you're getting from `request.getParameter("id1")` matches the id in the DB? Could you add a breakpoint there and inspect the actual runtime value? Also, this could be a charset encoding issue if your ids contain characters outside of the US-ASCII range.

Comment: I want to show the output by getting data from  DB but st provide null value.. Mick Mnemonic

Comment: @Faisal, sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. I asked if you are sure that the servlet is receiving the ids in correct format (and charset encoding). Have you tried to debug the id values that are being received in `processRequest`?

Comment: yup, i have check it, I am getting ID in servlet page from request page..I am getting ID as string and also matches the DB 'ID'.. @Mick

Comment: do proper debugging.. LINE BY LINE